# DataFrame groupby() on MultiIndex then apply on multiple columns leads to broadcasting problems

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, ta-lib

This is the setup:

```
arrays = [["2010-01-01","2010-01-01","2010-01-02","2010-01-02","2010-01-03","2010-01-03"],
                 ["MSFT", "AAPL", "MSFT", "AAPL","MSFT", "AAPL"]]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["date", "symbol"])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(6, 4), index=index, columns=["high", "low", "open", "close"])

def fn_sum(close, high, low):
    return close+high+low

def fn_plus(close):
        return close+1
```

The DF looks like this:

```
date       symbol   high        low        open        close

2010-01-01  MSFT  1.144042   0.889603   -0.193715   1.005927
            AAPL  0.433530  -0.291510    1.420505   0.326206
2010-01-02  MSFT -1.509419  -0.273476   -0.620735  -0.205946
            AAPL  0.454401  -0.085008    0.686485   1.309894
2010-01-03  MSFT  1.487588  -0.777500   -0.218993  -1.242664
            AAPL -0.456024  -0.819463   -2.224953   1.263124
```

I want to use technical analysis functions on all symbols with a groupby(), apply() fashion like this:

> df["1"] = df.groupby(level="symbol").apply(lambda x: fn_sum(x["close"], x["high"], x["low"]))

This results in a broadcasting error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,2) (3,) (6,2)
```

Performing the same on a singular column works though:

> df["2"] = df.groupby(level="symbol").close.apply(lambda x: fn_plus(x))

**Questions:**

- So how do I get this to work when using apply on multiple columns and combining them back to a DataFrame without broadcasting issues?
- Also I'm very grateful for a better implementation that works with MultiIndex DFs like above.

For more context: I want to use technical analysis functions from the TA-lib package. See: https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/func_groups/volatility_indicators.html

The functions look like this (for example):

> ATR(high, low, close[, timeperiod=?])
>
> Average True Range (Volatility Indicators)
>
> Inputs: prices: ['high', 'low', 'close'] 
>   Parameters: timeperiod: 14 
>   Outputs: real

I get the same broadcasting error as above in the contrived example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If multiple columns is necessary pass to function use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) or [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
s = (df.groupby(level="symbol", group_keys=False)
       .apply(lambda x: fn_sum(x["close"], x["high"], x["low"])))
df = df.join(s.rename('new'))
#alternative
#df = df.assign(new=s)
print (df)
                       high       low      open     close       new
date       symbol                                                  
2010-01-01 MSFT   -1.085631  0.997345  0.282978 -1.506295 -1.594580
           AAPL   -0.578600  1.651437 -2.426679 -0.428913  0.643924
2010-01-02 MSFT    1.265936 -0.866740 -0.678886 -0.094709  0.304487
           AAPL    1.491390 -0.638902 -0.443982 -0.434351  0.418136
2010-01-03 MSFT    2.205930  2.186786  1.004054  0.386186  4.778903
           AAPL    0.737369  1.490732 -0.935834  1.175829  3.403930
```

If only one column use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and specify column after `groupby`:

```
df['new1'] = df.groupby(level="symbol")['close'].transform(fn_plus)
print (df)
                       high       low      open     close      new1
date       symbol                                                  
2010-01-01 MSFT   -1.085631  0.997345  0.282978 -1.506295 -0.506295
           AAPL   -0.578600  1.651437 -2.426679 -0.428913  0.571087
2010-01-02 MSFT    1.265936 -0.866740 -0.678886 -0.094709  0.905291
           AAPL    1.491390 -0.638902 -0.443982 -0.434351  0.565649
2010-01-03 MSFT    2.205930  2.186786  1.004054  0.386186  1.386186
           AAPL    0.737369  1.490732 -0.935834  1.175829  2.175829
```